# compare empty string cshell

Tags: linux, unix, csh

i facing a problem with compare the empty string detected from grep file.
i want to detect empty file searched into the first if condition, but file i search that is empty, it cannot go into the if ($vg == "") then condition to echo the output and execute the cp condition.

code i use to find file:

```
set lvg =`find ${lward}/netlists/verilog/ -name "${subblock}.v"`
```

Below is the code:

```
foreach vg (${lvg})
 if ($vg == "") then
   echo "${subblock}.vg file not found"
 else if (${vg} =~ "*/${subblock}.vg") then
   cp -r "$vg" ./primetime/design/verilog/${subblock}.v
 endif 
end
```

Comment: use `if ( -s $vg )`  check  instead of  `if ($vg == "") `

Comment: erm, it still unable to get the output, i have try -z , -f